# Use ActiveStorage Image in wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, wicked-pdf

I can't get ActiveStorage images to work in production. I want to use a resized image (variant) within the body of the PDF I'm generating.

```
= image_tag(@post.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [150, 100]))
```

It worked in development but in production generating the PDF hangs indefinitely unless I take that line out.

I've tried things like `@post.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [150, 100]).processed.url` and setting `Rails.application.default_url_options = { host: "example.com" }`

Ironically when I restart Passenger it sends the PDF to the browser and it actually looks fine. The image is included.

This is similar:

```
= wicked_pdf_image_tag(@post.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [150, 100]).processed.url)
```

Rails 7.0.3, Ruby 3.1.2, wicked_pdf 2.6.3

Comment: I think what is happening here, is that `image_tag` outputs an `https://` url pointing to the same server, so when the request happens, in the middle of building the PDF, the `wkhtmltopdf` process reaches out to your server to get the asset, but your server is in the middle of processing the request to build the PDF, creating a deadlock. The solution for this is to make it so your passenger web server can handle more than one request at a time (at least 2). Otherwise, you'll need to cache your variant to a file and use a file reference instead of an HTTP one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Unixmonkey I added passenger_min_instances 3; to my server block in Nginx config and it worked initially but would hang Passenger under load. Since I didn't have the RAM to throw at increasing that number I came up with a different solution based on reading images from file.

```
= image_tag(active_storage_to_base64_image(@post.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [150, 100])))
```

Then I created a helper in application_helper.rb

```
def active_storage_to_base64_image(image)
  require "base64"
  file = File.open(ActiveStorage::Blob.service.path_for(image.processed.key))
  base64 = Base64.encode64(file.read).gsub(/\s+/, '')
  file.close
  "data:image/png;base64,#{Rack::Utils.escape(base64)}"
end
```

I've hard coded it for PNG files as that's all I needed. Only works for Disk storage. Would welcome improvements